# Sorting a column of a table in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using the following code :

```
Daily_intensity %>% 
  mutate(weekdays = weekdays(date)) %>% 
  group_by(weekdays) %>% 
  summarise(minutes_fairly_very_active = sum(fairlyactiveminutes + veryactiveminutes))
```

The result is not in the order of the weekdays. What should I add so that I get result in order, from Monday to Sunday?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the current output, and the data type of `weekdays`?   Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your question.

Comment: You need to change your `weekdays` variable to a factor: `mutate(weekdays = date |> weekdays() |> fct_relevel("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"))` and then add `arrange(weekdays)` at the end of your pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lubridate` instead of `base` and get an ordered factor of the desired kind without needing to specify the order of the weekdays yourself:

```r
mutate(weekdays = lubridate::wday(date, label = TRUE, week_start = 1))
```